# Need Help With SQL Server 2008 Join With 3 Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am wondering if someone can solve this for me please.

I am trying to do a join on two tables. One is a date calendar table with dates from the year 2000 until 2050. This table has column named Year_Month which I want to group by.
The 2nd table is a transaction table containing dates and other details.
What I want is to return all Year_Months with a count of the transaction records and a zero where data does not exist.

My query is as follows

```
select          dd.YR_MONTH, 
                a.dep_code,
                a.div_code,
                d.dep_name, 
                actions_assigned = isnull(count(a.action_id),0) 
from            DimDate dd
Left outer join sr_assigned_to a 
on              (assign_date =[DATE] or assign_date is null)
Left outer join sr_dep_codes d 
on              (d.dep_code = a.dep_code or d.dep_code is null) 
and             (d.div_code = a.div_code or d.div_code is null)
where           [date] between DATEADD(m,-13,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
                          and  DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
group by        a.dep_code, 
                a.div_code, 
                d.dep_name, 
                dd.YR_MONTH
```

The results returned are missing some months (in this example Oct 2016 is missing)

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

**Table Schemas**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sr_assigned_to](
    [request_id] [decimal](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [responsible_code] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [assign_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [reason_assigned] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [outcome_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [outcome_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [status_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [comments] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [client_notified] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [notified_via] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [date_notified] [datetime] NULL,
    [finalised_ind] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [assign_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [booked_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [booked_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [officer_notified] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [outcome_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [priority_code] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [action_format] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [collect_extras] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
    [serial_no] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [position_no] [decimal](3, 0) NULL,
    [after_pos_no] [decimal](3, 0) NULL,
    [amount_held] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [in_time_ind] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [escalated_ind] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [length_no] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [width_no] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [action_id] [decimal](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [div_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dep_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [taken_hrs] [decimal](8, 0) NULL,
    [over_hrs] [decimal](8, 0) NULL,
    [under_hrs] [decimal](8, 0) NULL,
    [posted_ind] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [change_booked_date] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [change_action_reqd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [change_action_officer] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [change_priority] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [skip_time_taken] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [udf_ind] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [gen_wflow_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_sr_assigned_to] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [action_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate](
    [DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [NEXT_DAY_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [YEAR] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [YEAR_QUARTER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [YEAR_MONTH] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ALT_YR_MONTH] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [YEAR_DAY_OF_YEAR] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QUARTER] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [MONTH] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DAY_OF_YEAR] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [DAY_OF_MONTH] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [DAY_OF_WEEK] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [YEAR_NAME] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [YEAR_QUARTER_NAME] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [YEAR_MONTH_NAME] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [YEAR_MONTH_NAME_LONG] [varchar](14) NOT NULL,
    [QUARTER_NAME] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [MONTH_NAME] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [MONTH_NAME_LONG] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [WEEKDAY_NAME] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [WEEKDAY_NAME_LONG] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_YEAR_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_YEAR_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_QUARTER_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_QUARTER_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_MONTH_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_MONTH_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SUN_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_TUE_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_WED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_THU_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_FRI_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [END_OF_WEEK_STARTING_SAT_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [QUARTER_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MONTH_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEEK_STARTING_SUN_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEEK_STARTING_MON_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEEK_STARTING_TUE_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEEK_STARTING_WED_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEEK_STARTING_THU_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEEK_STARTING_FRI_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEEK_STARTING_SAT_SEQ_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [JULIAN_DATE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_JULIAN_DATE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ISO_DATE] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ISO_WEEK_NO] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_NAME] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [ISO_YEAR_WEEK_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_M_D] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YYYY] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_MMM_D_YYYY] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_MMMMMMMMM_D_YYYY] [varchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YY] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_FORMAT_M_D_YY] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I ran the following (joins commented out)

```
select  ALT_YR_MONTH as YR_MONTH
--, a.dep_code,a.div_code,d.dep_name,actions_assigned = isnull(count(action_id),0) 
from DimDate 
--Left outer join sr_assigned_to a on (assign_date =[DATE] or assign_date is null)
--Left outer join sr_dep_codes d on (d.dep_code = a.dep_code or d.dep_code is null) and (d.div_code = a.div_code or d.div_code is null)
where [date] between DATEADD(m,-13,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)) and  DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
group by 
--a.dep_code,a.div_code,d.dep_name, 
ALT_YR_MONTH
```

and it returns 2016-10 as one of the results

[image]

But if I run the code uncommented

```
select          ALT_YR_MONTH as YR_MONTH,
                a.dep_code,
                a.div_code,
                d.dep_name,
                actions_assigned = isnull(count(action_id),0) 
from            DimDate 
Left outer join sr_assigned_to a 
on              (assign_date =[DATE] or assign_date is null)
Left outer join sr_dep_codes d 
on              (d.dep_code = a.dep_code or d.dep_code is null) 
and             (d.div_code = a.div_code or d.div_code is null)
where           [date] between DATEADD(m,-13,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
                       and  DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
group by        a.dep_code,
                a.div_code,
                d.dep_name, 
                ALT_YR_MONTH
```

It drops out 2016-10 where there is no data for the year and month in sr_assigned_to

Comment: First thing to check: your DimDate table. Is there a 2016-10 YR_MONTH?

Comment: Yes my DimDate table contains the yr_month 2016-10

Comment: Can you post some sample source data? Definitely some information we're missing in the question.

Comment: Just to be sure - your table definition has a `YEAR_MONTH` and an `ALT_YR_MONTH` column, but no `YR_MONTH` column in DimDate. So, that would imply your query isn't exact, or your table definitions aren't. If the query isn't exactly correct, it's much harder to diagnose something that, say, breaks the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Suggestion: Run the query with both `LEFT JOIN` and their columns commented out. Confirm you do see 2016-10. If you don't see it when you put the joins and their columns back in, then something in your query may be forcing a `LEFT JOIN` to act as an `INNER JOIN`. If you're looking for a column from one of the `LEFT JOIN` tables to have a value, make sure you allow for that value to be NULL.

Comment: If you run the query without the joins and 2016-10 is missing, then your data is the problem. Again, based on what we see as the query, you'd want to check the `date` for the rows where `YEAR_MONTH` is 2016-10, and make sure they're in range.

Comment: OK, We now know the data is good - not only that there is a 2016-10, but that the dates attached fall into your date range. Next - run the query again, with the `LEFT JOIN`s in place, but with the columns from `a` and `d` excluded fro the `SELECT` list and the `GROUP BY`. Does "2016-10" still show up (I expect it to, but something weird is apparently going on here).

Answer (score 0):

I've set up the tables as per your posted definitions (there wasn't one for sr_dep_codes so I created it with just the fields used in the query) and input some basic data into the tables - one DimDate entry that has a matching sr_assigned_to row and one that doesn't and using bottom version of the query (with the correct reference to ALT_YR_MONTH) it behaves as expected:

```
select          ALT_YR_MONTH as YR_MONTH,
                a.dep_code,
                a.div_code,
                d.dep_name,
                actions_assigned = isnull(count(action_id),0) 
from            DimDate 
Left outer join sr_assigned_to a 
on              (assign_date =[DATE] or assign_date is null)
Left outer join sr_dep_codes d 
on              (d.dep_code = a.dep_code or d.dep_code is null) 
and             (d.div_code = a.div_code or d.div_code is null)
where           [date] between DATEADD(m,-13,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
                       and  DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
group by        a.dep_code,
                a.div_code,
                d.dep_name, 
                ALT_YR_MONTH
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Many thanks for going to the trouble of testing. If I run your code against my data I get a different result. I will have to do some data quality checks. You have confirmed that my logic is correct. Cheers.

Comment: @JeffW - yeah, sorry it didn't solve it but hopefully it will get you a bit closer. If you want (and are able) to post the structure for the sr_dep_codes table and some data (both that "works" and that the 2016-10 row that doesn't) I can plug them into my environment here and see if I can replicate what you're seeing.